# Regex help, match produces extra spaces

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am using the `boost/regex.hpp` library. The regex is intended to match a floating point number or one of an arbitrary list of math operators. The trailing `a` is a place holder because the current code to construct the regex leaves a `|` at the end, and I haven't fixed it yet. My regex is:

```
(?:([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)|(\s*sqrt\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*exp\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\^)|(\s*log2\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*log10\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*neg\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*floor\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*log\((.+?)\)\s*)|(\s*fact\((.+?)\)\s*)|(/)|([*])|([+])|([-])|a)
```

and my test string is:

```
4.5 + 9.6e8 + sqrt(5)
```

The resulting match is:

```
4.5                                          +  9.6e8                                          +    sqrt(5) 5
```

I'm not sure why there are so many spaces between the captures.

The printing code is

```
boost::regex reg(token);
boost::smatch m;
string s = input;
while (boost::regex_search(s, m, reg)) {
    for (int i = 1; i < m.size(); ++i) cout << m[i] << " ";
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

Comment: How are you printing the match?  The problem seems to be in that part of the code.

Comment: @tripleee I added the printing code. Later I was intending to replace the `cout` with code to add the tokens to a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of capturing parentheses and you are printing a space between each capture group.  Many of your capture groups are empty.  Maybe you want to refactor your regex to only capture what you really want.

Comment: Are you saying the captures in between all the | are filled with a space? I thought they would be ignored and be unavailable when reading the match object.

Comment: No, I'm saying your code prints `<< " "` between each of those empty groups.

Comment: Right. I so the `smatch` object's size is based on the number of `()` not on how many captures it successfully makes?

Comment: I've added `if (m[i].str().size() > 0)` before the `cout` and now the match looks as expected.

Comment: @sehe My bad! No excuse for poor SO etiquette.